# How can I create unit tests for a Xamarin project in Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, unit-testing, xamarin, xunit

I have Xamarin Android project created in Visual Studio.
I would like to create unit test project for my mobile app. 
I tired xUnit Test Project but I have problem with linking both projects:
[Linking xUnit with Android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDgEY.png)

I tried also Unit Test App (android) and I didn't have any problems with linking both projects but in this project I have problems and I don't know how can I initialize/use classes/functions from my main android project. I'm trying `using (MainProjectName)` but Unit tests project doesn't see any other projects/directories.

EDIT:
When I try to build Unit Test App I get an error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA5211: Embedded wear app package name differs from handheld app package name (com.companyname.matchfinder != UnitTests.UnitTests). (XA5211) (UnitTests)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem,you can try to open the `.csproj` file of your Android app and find the project reference you need to work. It might look like this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyWearApp\MyWearApp.csproj">
   <Project>{D80E1FEF-653B-448C-B2AA-609C74E88340}</Project>
   <Name>MyWearApp</Name>
   <IsAppExtension>True</IsAppExtension>
</ProjectReference>
```

The problem is with the extension part. Simply remove the `IsAppExtension` line and any other than Project and Name.

For more details, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/xamarin/android/wear/deploy-test/packaging?tabs=windows